# Random number generating in haskell

Tags: haskell, random

When running `genRandTupe` I continuously get the same random numbers, however when running `genrandList` with `gen` as the argument i get a new set of numbers every time. How would I solve this? Why doesn't `g = newStdGen` generate a new random number?

```
import System.Random
import System.IO.Unsafe

type RandTupe = (Int,Int)
genRandTupe :: IO RandTupe
genRandTupe = let [a,b] = genrandList g in return (a,b) where g = newStdGen
genrandList gen = let g = unsafePerformIO gen in take 2 (randomRs (1, 20) g)
gen = newStdGen
```

Comment: If you actually *want* a different random number each time, you need to either call `randomRIO` and put `IO` in the type signature, or call `randomR`, take a seed as input, and return a new seed as output. I'm *sure* somebody else has already asked about this somewhere on SO.

Comment: I'll add my voice to what hopefully should become a choir: **don't use `unsafePerformIO`!**  (Unless you really, *really*, **really** know what you're doing.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`genRandTupe` is a [constant applicative form](https://wiki.haskell.org/Constant_applicative_form). That means any local variables in its `let` or `where` blocks are memoised. Usually quite a convenient feat!

In your case, it means that the list `[a,b]` is only computed once in your whole program. The way it is computed is actually illegal (*don't use `unsafePerformIO`*!), but it doesn't really matter because it only happens once anyway. Wrapping this constant tuple then into `IO` with `return` is actually completely superfluent, you could as well have written

```
genRandTupe' :: RandTupe
genRandTupe' = let [a,b] = genrandList g in (a,b)
 where g = newStdGen
```

OTOH, when you evaluate `genrandList gen` (not a CAF) in multiple separate places, the result will not necessarily be stored. Instead, that function is calculated anew, using `unsafePerformIO` to **unsafely** modify the global state (or maybe not... the compiler is actually free to optimise this away since, you know, `genRandList` is supposedly a pure function...) and therefore yield a different result each time.

The correct thing, of course, is to stay the heck away from `unsafePerformIO`. There's actually no need at all to do IO in `genRandList`, since it already accepts a random generator... just bind that generator out from IO before passing it:

```
genRandTupe'' :: IO RandTupe
genRandTupe'' = do
    g <- newStdGen
    let [a,b] = genrandList g
    return (a,b)

randListFrom :: RandomGen g => g -> [Int]
randListFrom g = take 2 (randomRs (1, 20) g)
```

Note that, because the `let [a,b] = ...` now is in a `do` block, it's now in the `IO` monad, decoupled from the CAF closure of `genRandTupe''`.

Comment: Thanks, definitely helped.

Comment: Sorry about the alarmist tone, but `unsafePerformIO` is a pest. (And, it really doesn't belong to Haskell at all, just to the Foreign Function Interface.)